# Sitecore 7.2 RSS feed returning 404

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, iis, rss, sitecore

I am running a Sitecore 7.2 instance on 2012R2 running in MVC and am running into a bizarre issue with the built-in Sitecore RSS feeds. I have created an RSS feed using Sitecore successfully and the actual link to the XML file works and never goes down. That is to say, I can preview it through Sitecore client and reach the public URL of the XML feed on both staging and production servers without issue.

I then created a Simple Sitecore object that takes in the XML feed URL, parses it and displays it in a nicely-formatted view (cshtml view and controller). The object works, pulls the Sitecore-generated RSS feed and formats it, then spits it out in a nice format on a page. Yay.

Except over the past few weeks I've been running into an issue where this object goes into a fail state, stating that the URL it is trying to read (the public URL of the Sitecore feed) is invalid and returns a 404. When in this error state, I can still navigate directly to the public URL and see the XML feed live, so it's not the actual feed going down.

A restart of the application (eg. by modifying the web.config file and uploading it to the server) fixes this issue. After the application restart, everything is back to working again, until a later time when it crashes again.

I do have the IIS server do an application pool restart every morning around 3am and have noticed over the past week that after the application pool restart the RSS Object is in this fail state. Restarting the Sitecore Application (again via a web.config chage, for example), fixes everything.

This only happen to the RSS objects that are referencing the Sitecore feed itself on the same server. For example, the RSS Object on the production server referencing the RSS Feed on the production server goes down. The RSS object on the production server referencing the staging server RSS feed stays up, as does the RSS object referencing an external feed.

Needless to say, I am stumped. I haven't been able to find anything on the internet from people having a similar issue. Has anyone ever experienced this with Sitecore's RSS feeds before?